# run Javascript code using php

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to get files from a text files in a directory and show them inside a figcaption tag. I tried to echo a javascript code to get the figcaption by id and change the innerHTML however that doesn't work my code is

```php
<?php
$images = glob("upload_pic//*.png");
 $files = glob("bio//*.txt");
$char = 'A'; 
$char <= 'Z';
foreach(array_reverse($images) as $image) {
echo '<figure>';
echo '<img onload="fadeIn(this)" src="'.$image.'"  style="display:none;"/>';
echo '<figcaption id="'.$char.'"></figcaption>';
echo '</figure>';
 $char++;
 }
foreach(array_reverse($files) as  $index => $file) {
echo '<script>';
echo 'setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("'.$char.'").innerHTML ="hello"; }, 3000);';
echo '</script>';
}

?>
```

Every thing works fine and looks good until it reaches this line

```php
echo 'setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("'.$char.'").innerHTML ="hello"; }, 3000);';
```

and that's where I get 4 errors all saying the same thing:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Is there any way that I could insert the text from the files in this directory into the figcaption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I'm a fan of this style of code, but your use of `$char` is all screwed up.  You iterate through it on the first loop, but not on the second... so, the second loop is always the same ('N' or some other craziness).  Easy fix is to use a second counter, assuming that the $images and $files array are in order together and match up.

```
<?php
$images = glob("upload_pic//*.png");
 $files = glob("bio//*.txt");
$char = 'A'; 
$char2 = 'A';
foreach(array_reverse($images) as $image) {
    echo '<figure>';
    echo '<img onload="fadeIn(this)" src="'.$image.'"  style="display:none;"/>';
    echo '<figcaption id="'.$char++.'"></figcaption>';
    echo '</figure>';
}
foreach(array_reverse($files) as  $index => $file) {
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("'.$char2++.'").innerHTML ="hello"; }, 3000);';
    echo '</script>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much that solved my issue, and I'm kind of new to php this is my first project in php so I wasn't sure how to use the code in the best and factional way. Thank you alot :)

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because `innerHTML` property is not getting an element to work for. 
It is clear, you have some problem in your `getElementById()` section. And the problem is the parameter you are using within the method.
Best way to use your code is like this :

```
<?php
$images = glob("upload_pic//*.png"); $files = glob("bio//*.txt");
$char = 'A'; $i = 'A';

foreach(array_reverse($images) as $image) { ?>

 <figure>
  <img onload="fadeIn(this)" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" style="display:none"/>
<figcaption id="<?php echo $char;"></figcaption>
</figure>

<?php $char++; }

foreach(array_reverse($files) as  $index => $file) { ?>

<script>
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("<?php echo $i++ ?>").innerHTML ="hello"; }, 3000);
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: That code makes it clearer to read and esair on the server however it didn't solve my issue now I got 4 lines shown as the flowing
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("E").innerHTML ="hello"; }, 3000);;

and they all have the id as E so is there anyway that start ids from A but stop when ever there the figcaption id count stops ?